# How to call a function inside a function with button (Javascript)?

Tags: function, button, onclick, call

So my problem is, when I enter this code:

```
function exemple() {
    var hey;
    function message(){
       hey = true 
    }}

<input type="button" value="hello" onclick="message()">
```

It says ''message is not defined''.... so I was wondering if there is a simple way to call a function inside another function with an onclick event on a button... I've been looking for help on internet and stackoverflow but couldn't find the answer to my question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are calling message() on your HTML tag. You should either call exemple();  or put message() function outside the exemple() function.

This should work :

```
<input type="button" value="hello" onclick="exemple()">

  var hey;
  function exemple() {
      message();
   }

    function message(){
       hey = true;
      console.log("It's working");
      alert("Hi");
    }
```

Comment: Problem is: I want to call only message() because in my exemple() function there is another function that I dont want to call. Also, i want it to be INSIDE exemple() because im using its variables...

Comment: I am not sure if this is the real code or not.  But when you create the hay var as global variable it will be changed when you run the exempleI() function. So the variable hey is already updated. I don't see why you have to call a function inside the another function.